# JSX Put Element before JS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am learning React.

What I have is this

```
return (
    flights.map(flight => <FlightCard info={flight}/>)
)
```

But I want something like a parent element so that all FlightCard elements will be styled. But I get an error with the message **'flight' is not defined'** when i wrap it within another element.

```
return (
    <div>
        flights.map(flight => <FlightCard info={flight}/>
    </div)
)
```

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to wrap it inside curly brackets, so the compiler tries to find `{flight}` variable, but it's not initialized, because whole line was treated as a string.

```
return (
   <div>
      {flights.map(flight => <FlightCard style={cardStyle} info={flight} />)}
   </div>
)
```

Even if `{cardStyle}` happens before `{flight}`, it doesn't throw any error because you have probably initialized `cardStyle` before.

Comment: I also had the impression to wrap it in curly brackets but once I try it I will get another error Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," -behind the second bracket

Comment: @UnknownJoe Yeah, we forgot together to close the `map` function. Ive edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react 16, you can use React.Fragment as your parent element.

```
<React.Fragment>
    {myArray.map()...}
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: You answer is more like a comment that you can post under the question :)

Comment: I read about React.Fragment which equal <></> and dissolve into nothing in the DOM but I think in this case I cannot use them, because I want to have a parent so that I can style my FlightCard elements :)